# change Domain MX

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I have a windows server and I set my domain name servers to this server. now I want send email from another server, really my web application and mail server aren't on a same server. the mail server is Linux CentOS. and there are many mail accounts available on it. so it has no problem. now I want to to send and receive emails from the linux server and my website be on the windows server. so I changed MX record of my domain to Linux server. but when I send mail from the mail server to gmail.com it's response is:

```
 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname
```

what is wrong? I searched for this problem but I couldn't solve this problem. I want to ask you what is the steps to change mail server? did I forget some Steps?

Answer (score 4):

Based upon the error message it would appear that you need to configure [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)s for the host. This is normally done with a PTR record. For example you might have a host mail.example.com

```
mail.example.com IN A 192.0.2.1
```

and a PTR record

```
1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR mail.example.com
```